# Open html link from Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I write an extension for Chrome. My extension is very simple.

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href='http://example.com'>Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I here is my manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Something else",
    "short_name": "Something else",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version":"1.0.0.0",
    "description": "Something else",
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Click here"
},
"icons": {"48": "48.png",
    "16": "16.png",
    "128": "128.png"}
}
```

I'm building a chrome extension. Everything is OK. But when I run the extension, clicking on above link doesn't load the page example.com. How can I fix this?

Comment: just use `target="_blank"` attribute for the link, see also [Keep Popup Open when Opening a new Page](//stackoverflow.com/q/35272905)

Comment: Thank you :) I mistake. I use parent='_blank' :)), so it doesn't work. Target, not parent :)